# Android application doesn't start (cocos2d-x)

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I use the last version of Cocos2d-x (2.1.4). It's a strange error because I can't replicate it. On my device all works fine but users that using my app send me following logs. What the failure it is?

When I read comments on my mail they talking about sleeping mode. They trying to sleep my app and now it never go back again :) Restaring of the phone also doesn't solve the problem...

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=2 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xcee8
| sysTid=1454 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:727)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread" prio=5 tid=41 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40acf7b0 self=0x8df308
| sysTid=22307 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8745936
at android.hardware.SensorManager.sensors_data_poll(Native Method)
at android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread$SensorThreadRunnable.run(SensorManager.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #16" prio=5 tid=63 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4091e380 self=0x85ea98
| sysTid=26048 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8377432
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #15" prio=5 tid=62 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a6eb50 self=0x7a20b0
| sysTid=25658 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7528968
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #14" prio=5 tid=61 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409dea38 self=0x715848
| sysTid=19192 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8010272
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #13" prio=5 tid=60 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40af6a50 self=0x5f2528
| sysTid=19109 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7430984
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #12" prio=5 tid=59 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a98ee8 self=0x715db0
| sysTid=17351 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7207576
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #11" prio=5 tid=58 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409404f8 self=0x787dd8
| sysTid=16394 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7382408
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #10" prio=5 tid=57 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b5ad78 self=0x716b98
| sysTid=14029 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8039104
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #9" prio=5 tid=56 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408f61a8 self=0x546188
| sysTid=4918 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4913536
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-83" prio=5 tid=55 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b11f88 self=0x35c380
| sysTid=4002 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3681600
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at com.google.android.gsf.Gservices$1.run(Gservices.java:78)

"gps_s5pc110" prio=5 tid=54 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a5fe70 self=0x34c008
| sysTid=2274 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2960880
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #8" prio=5 tid=53 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b13738 self=0x496488
| sysTid=2271 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2877168
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=52 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408a4100 self=0x48ee08
| sysTid=1633 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4779840
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x408a4288> (a java.lang.VMThread)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1424)
at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:337)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:411)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1021)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"GpsLocationProvider" prio=5 tid=51 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405c89d0 self=0x3530f0
| sysTid=1602 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3829536
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at com.android.server.location.GpsLocationProvider$GpsLocationProviderThread.run(GpsLocationProvider.java:2859)

"Binder Thread #7" prio=5 tid=50 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407ac390 self=0x2cb608
| sysTid=1596 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3339048
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #6" prio=5 tid=49 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409080c0 self=0x2d2c30
| sysTid=1594 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=869832
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #5" prio=5 tid=48 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40864678 self=0x34e6a8
| sysTid=1593 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3107216
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #4" prio=5 tid=47 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4090aef8 self=0x2d8c08
| sysTid=1592 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3019728
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=46 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407da308 self=0x397af0
| sysTid=1576 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3068488
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@407b4110" daemon prio=5 tid=45 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4062bd68 self=0xd4448
| sysTid=1562 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2992352
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4071a4f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:107)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:80)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:102)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"ThrottleService" prio=5 tid=44 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4084fe70 self=0x2bb7d0
| sysTid=1546 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2867840
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"LocationManagerService" prio=5 tid=43 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407ddec0 self=0x2bba70
| sysTid=1544 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3057792
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.run(LocationManagerService.java:563)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"watchdog" prio=5 tid=42 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40516a38 self=0x2cad10
| sysTid=1537 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=943528
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40516a38> (a com.android.server.Watchdog)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
at com.android.server.Watchdog.run(Watchdog.java:400)

"backup" prio=5 tid=40 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408c3f58 self=0x3c7580
| sysTid=1516 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3962552
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=39 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4089e920 self=0x3c4948
| sysTid=1514 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3946176
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=38 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408719e8 self=0x3c39e0
| sysTid=1515 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3946448
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AudioService" prio=5 tid=37 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4086ee70 self=0xd91e8
| sysTid=1513 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=889632
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.media.AudioService$AudioSystemThread.run(AudioService.java:1602)

"EncryptConnector" prio=5 tid=36 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408699c8 self=0x3c2108
| sysTid=1511 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3940928
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:112)
at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:85)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"EncryptService" prio=5 tid=33 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40856df8 self=0x3c0cc8
| sysTid=1509 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3935744
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with cocos2d-x 2.1.4: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/3029. It only happens on some Android devices, for me it was happening on Kindle Fire. I would revert to cocos2d-x 2.1.3 or wait until the next version comes out that fixes this bug.